# MySQL modifying order by rand() to other methods

Tags: mysql, sql, join, random, union

I am now trying to make random selections from each grouped column array, with chances followed by the weight of each row. For example, I have a table (DemoTable) like this:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23470/3/0

| Name | State | Grade | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | NY | 100 | 1 |
| Liam | NY | 90 | 2 |
| Olivia | NY | 90 | 3 |
| Emma | NY | 80 | 4 |
| James | CA | 10 | 1 |
| Henry | CA | 20 | 1 |
| Mia | NJ | 50 | 1 |
| Ava | NJ | 30 | 4 |

For State = 'NY', there are four rows with grade array: [100, 90, 90, 80] and the weight [1, 2, 3, 4], respectively. So 80 has the largest chance to be picked while 100 has the least within its State group.
I made a query for it:

```
SELECT a.*,
(SELECT b.Grade FROM DemoTable b WHERE a.State = b.State 
ORDER BY RAND() * -b.Weight LIMIT 1) AS 'random_val' FROM DemoTable a;
```

and it worked with the result:

| Name | State | Grade | Weight | random_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | NY | 100 | 1 | 80 |
| Liam | NY | 90 | 2 | 80 |
| Olivia | NY | 90 | 3 | 80 |
| Emma | NY | 80 | 4 | 90 |
| James | CA | 10 | 1 | 20 |
| Henry | CA | 20 | 1 | 10 |
| Mia | NJ | 50 | 1 | 30 |
| Ava | NJ | 30 | 4 | 30 |

Though, I would like to know if there is any other method like join or union instead of using order by rand() alone. 
Is there any other way to modify my MySQL query that gives the same result? 
I've searched for solving this problem all day, but couldn't find the proper way to do so; and that's why I asked here for the aid. 
I would sincerely appreciate if I could get some advice.

Comment: @philipxy - What is the folk theory you refer to?  *(In MySQL `RAND()` **is** executed independently for each row, as demonstrated in the manual... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand )*

Comment: @Jay In MySQL8 I can think of several options, does it ***have*** to be MySQL 5.7 *(which is nearly six years old, and super-ceded by MySQL 8.0 three years ago)*.

Comment: @MatBailie it doesn't have to be MySQL 5.7. Could you offer some hints with using MySQL8?

Comment: Show desired output. Does it must contain 3 rows only, one row per state?

Comment: @Akina, it ***does*** show the desired results; the source table plus one additional column

Comment: I presume you ***want*** the possibility of each `Name` in the same `State` yielding a different `random_val`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first attempt using analytic functions, though I suspect yours is faster over larger datasets...

```
WITH
  ranged AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    SUM(weight) OVER (PARTITION BY state ORDER BY id) - weight   AS weight_range_lower,
    SUM(weight) OVER (PARTITION BY state ORDER BY id)            AS weight_range_upper,
    SUM(weight) OVER (PARTITION BY state            ) * rand()   AS rand_threshold
  FROM
    DemoTable
)
SELECT
  ranged.*,
  lookup.grade   AS random_grade
FROM
  ranged
INNER JOIN
  ranged  AS lookup
    ON  lookup.state               = ranged.state
    AND lookup.weight_range_lower <= ranged.rand_threshold
    AND lookup.weight_range_upper >  ranged.rand_threshold
ORDER BY
  ranged.id
```

Or, if you want all members of the same state to be given the same random_grade...

```
SELECT
  *,
  FIRST_VALUE(grade) OVER (PARTITION BY state ORDER BY weight * rand() DESC)
FROM
  DemoTable
ORDER BY
  id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=133f9e86b013a477ac342d0295132dd5

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I couldn't think of using this way. It works perfectly fine with giving me the same result :)